# Convert managed unsigned char* into a jbyte*

Tags: c#, c++, java-native-interface

How can I convert a managed unsigned char* into a jbyte*?
since I'm new to this, a snippet would be helpful too.

here is my native code:-

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_me_NativeCaller_processImages
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass c, jbyteArray front, jbyteArray back){
unsigned char* frontBuffer = convertJByteArrayIntoUnsignedChar(env, front);
unsigned char* backBuffer = convertJByteArrayIntoUnsignedChar(env, back);
System::Collections::Generic::List<cli::array<unsigned char>^>^ returnedValue = processImages(frontBuffer,backBuffer);
jbyte* bytes;
bytes = returnedValue[1];
bytes = returnedValue[2];
jbyteArray intermediateArray1 = env->NewByteArray(1);
env->SetByteArrayRegion(intermediateArray1,0,1,bytes);

return static_cast<jobject>(intermediateArray1);
```

}

here at `bytes = returnedValue[1];`I'm getting an error saying "a value of type cli::array^ cannot be assign to an entity of type jbyte*"

c# code which returns a List of byte[] :-

```
public static List<byte[]> processImages(byte[] frontImage, byte[] backImage)
    {
        CallProcessFrontBackAndMICR(frontImage,backImage);

        List<Image> imagesToReturn = GetAllPages(tiffFileBuffer);//convert byte[] into two separate images
        front = imagesToReturn[0];
        back = imagesToReturn[1];

        List<byte[]> bytesToReturn = new List<byte[]>();
        bytesToReturn.Add(imageToByteArray(front));
        bytesToReturn.Add(imageToByteArray(back));

        return bytesToReturn;
    }
```

it's really helpful if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Good question. Do you mean jbyteArray by "jbyte*"? And do you really want the bytes or is this a string? (You can easily do either but I guess you'll want the more convenient type!)

Comment: Coming right up. Have you tried anything btw? Always good to post that in SO.

Comment: I have a managed unsigned char* array, and I tried to convert into a jbyteArray with SetByteArrayRegion() method. but it gives me an error saying cannot convert managed unsigned char* into jbyte*

Comment: Oh right, in that case the answer i've just posted may not help, sorry I got that info late. Something else will be going on then. How are you manageing your unsigned char *? Have you actually got a const unsigned char * here?

Comment: I'm not good at explaining it in technically,but what I can say is my c# code is returning a list of Byte[] array to JNI native wrapper. so my native wrapper receives a System::Collections::Generic::List<cli::array<unsigned char>^>^ which I should pass to Java client as a jObject.

Comment: You might be having trouble with your conversion to unsigned char *. Is it contiguous from c#? Worth checking. Adding c# tag to get an expert in, and please have confidence to post your code!

Comment: please check the edited post, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a data in `unsigned char *` format to a `jbyteArray` which is `byte[]` in Java, if I remember rightly you want to do something like:

```
JNIEnv *env... //usually from your method signature in the jni
unsigned char *myCharData; // by stipulation you have this somehow.
const int yourArraySize = // as per usual number of elements in the char *
jbyteArray myJByteArray = env->NewByteArray(yourArraySize);
env->SetByteArrayREgion(myJByteArray, 0, yourArraySize, (jbyte *) myCharData);

// your myJByteArray is ready to use. Don't forget to memory manage your myCharData, mind!
```

The c-style cast works given the type definition of the jbyte, which we can assume is safe in this implementation.

At the time of writing this question, I haven't been aware where the data was coming from, so taking a guess, Android-specific docs, can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html).

Comment: Re: `NewStringUTF` is probably wrong for strings. `myCString` is likely to be a character set/encoding like Windows-1251 or similar, which isn't compatible with _modified UTF-8_ for much of the character set.

Comment: @TomBlodget Fair enough. I put a answer in to this question *before* the OP revealed the Windows/C# origin of the data. Will make an edit. If you're good on C# to JVM transfer via JNI I'm sure the OP would  appreciate your input!