# Convert managed unsigned char* array into a jbyteArray

Tags: c#, java, c++, java-native-interface

How can I convert a managed unsigned `char*` into a `jbyte*`?

since I'm new to this, a snippet would be helpful too.

here is my native code:-

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_me_NativeCaller_processImages
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass c, jbyteArray front, jbyteArray back){
unsigned char* frontBuffer = convertJByteArrayIntoUnsignedChar(env, front);
unsigned char* backBuffer = convertJByteArrayIntoUnsignedChar(env, back);
System::Collections::Generic::List<cli::array<unsigned char>^>^ returnedValue = processImages(frontBuffer,backBuffer);
jbyte* bytes;
bytes = returnedValue[1];
bytes = returnedValue[2];
jbyteArray intermediateArray1 = env->NewByteArray(1);
env->SetByteArrayRegion(intermediateArray1,0,1,bytes);

return static_cast<jobject>(intermediateArray1);
}
```

here at `bytes = returnedValue[1];`I'm getting an error saying `a value of type cli::array<unsigned char,1>^ cannot be assign to an entity of type jbyte*`

c# code which returns a List of `byte[]` :-

```
public static List<byte[]> processImages(byte[] frontImage, byte[] backImage)
    {
        CallProcessFrontBackAndMICR(frontImage,backImage);

        List<Image> imagesToReturn = GetAllPages(tiffFileBuffer);//convert byte[] into two separate images
        front = imagesToReturn[0];
        back = imagesToReturn[1];

        List<byte[]> bytesToReturn = new List<byte[]>();
        bytesToReturn.Add(imageToByteArray(front));
        bytesToReturn.Add(imageToByteArray(back));

        return bytesToReturn;
    }
```

it's really helpful if someone can help me with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert managed unsigned char\* into a jbyte\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994742/convert-managed-unsigned-char-into-a-jbyte)